# ¿Como mostrar/ocultar div con Angular?

Tags: angular

Tengo un `div` que quiero mostrar cuando el usuario termine de introducir un codigo en un `ng-otp-input`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta el momento intente realizarlo con la propiedad `ngIf` pero no me ha funcionado. Y es que la lógica va algo así: Cuando el usuario terminé de escribir el codigo, automaticamente verifica ese codigo y te envia a la siguiente pantalla, pero yo quiero que antes que me envíe a la siguiente pantalla me muestre el `div` que quiero ocultar/mostrar con `ngIf`

```
//varible donde almaceno el estado del div
  verificado = false;

  onOtpChange(otp: string) {
    this.otp = otp;
    this.cellPhone = this.bookingService.bookingModel.patient?.phone
    if (this.cellPhone && this.otp) {
      this.bookingService.checkOtpCode(this.cellPhone, this.otp).subscribe(res => {
        //Si la respuesta de la api ha salido bien
        if(res){
          //Mostra el div
          this.verificado = true
          //Y luego cerra el modal y mandame a la siguiente ventana
          this.dialogRef.close(true);
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

En el html del div que quiero mostrar tengo algo asi:

```html
<div class="verified" *ngIf="verificado">
  <img src="../../../../assets/img/otpVerified.png" alt="OTP">
  <br/>
  <p class="verified">¡Código verificado con Éxito!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Te lleva a la siguiente pantalla porque tú estás haciendo eso.... quiero decir, si no quieres que te lleve a la siguiente pantalla automáticamente para qué tienes el `this.dialogRef.close(true);`?? Elimina esa línea y ya no se cerrará el dialog. O ponla en un timeout para que de tiempo a mostrar el gráfico antes de cerrarse. Asumo que el método `onOtpChange` se dispara tras cada pulsación del usuario vaya. La verdad es que nunca usé el componente ese, pero por el nombre... :)

Comment: Si, ya lo logré! Era algo sencillo, solo tenia que llamar el div y en el setTimeOut luego de unos segundos cerrar el modal. Mil Gracias!